# What does domain-specific protocol mean?

Tags: microservices

I am reading about microservices communication style, and there is a style [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/domain-specific.html) called "domain-specific protocol" which i don't understand.

Can anyone please describe it with simple words?

Comment: The "Examples" section below on that page doesn't clear it up for you? If our domain is video streaming, it doesn't make sense to use SMTP.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"domain-specific protocol" means a protocol that's purpose-built for the task at hand (for example SMTP is built for sending email, RTSP is built for streaming video).

The alternative would be a generic message-passing system (such as a message queue or a generic RPC system like gRPC, DCOM, ...) where only the messages themselves are domain-specific, but the protocol itself is built in a way to flexibly adapt to different purposes.

Comment: I am trying to understand. Is the HTTP domain-specific too?

Comment: @AminShojaei: that's a tough one. Nominally it has been designed to transfer file contents, but it's being used in a manner much more like an RPC system (see REST-ful requests). I'd say most uses of HTTP that aren't straight up "display this website" should be counted as using a generic protocol (i.e. not domain-specific).

Comment: O OK. So the "domain-specific" isn't an style of communication. It's just an adjective to describe purpose a technical protocol. I was confused because it is categorized as a communication style(or pattern)! Thank you

Comment: In the end *something* about the communication will have to be domain-specific, but the question here is, is the *protocol* itself domain-specific (i.e. is it specific to the task at hand), or is it a more generic protocol transferring messages/procedure calls/whatchamacallits that are domain specific.

Comment: OMG you sound like a sudoku puzzle